# Python, finding a specific line based on multiple coniditions in a line

Tags: python, max, conditional-statements, min, multiple-conditions

I have a data set with the following numbers:

```
1 30.0 13.4545 
2 30.0 10.5578 
3 30.0 12.5578 
4  5.0 5.224
```

I have the following code that prints out the line with the smallest float based on the second float.

```
with open(fn) as f:
   print min(f, key=lambda line: float(line.split()[1]))
```

I am trying to figure out how to print the line with the largest first float, but if the floats are the same, then print the line with the smallest 3rd float within the group of lines with the 1st floats

it should print out:

```
2 30.0 10.5578
```

I thought of something like this:

```
 with open(fn) as f:
      cpu = max(f, key=lambda line: float(line.split()[1]))
      for line in f:
           if cpu in line > 1:
                print min(f, cpu, key=lambda line: float(line.split()[1]))
```

but no luck, I keep on printing out either the max or the min number without looking at the two conditions.

Comment: Since your condition depends on the values in multiple lines you're either going to have to read the entire file into memory to read it multiple times. The code you have doesn't work because the `max()` call reads the whole file, so there's nothing left to consume in the following `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's possible to do what you're asking with a lambda, the resulting lambda will be an unholy abomination that kills kittens, too. In all seriousness, this isn't a good place for a lambda because, barring some incredibly awful code, variable assignment isn't possible in a lambda, and variable assignment would make this a much easier problem.

Now, onto the issue itself. Your question is, essentially, how to sort items in descending order by their second value, then ascending order by their third value.

The item with the biggest second element and smallest third element can also be described as the item with the biggest second element and smallest *negative* third element.

To do that in Python, we can create a function to use as our key. This function takes each line, cuts out the first element of the line (because it's not relevant), and makes the third value negative.

You can do it with list comprehensions:

```
def myKey(line):
    key = [float(i) for i in line.split()[1:]]
    key[1] *= -1
    return key

print max(x, key=myKey)
```

Or with `map()`

```
def myKey(line):
    key = map(float, line.split()[1:])
    key[1] *= -1
    return key

print max(x, key=myKey)
```

And, sure enough, the output is:

```
2 30.0 10.5578
```

Comment: thank you!, I did by writing to two separate files, and find the max in one, then writing to another file and finding the max of that set, but that didn't seem too efficient

Comment: I love reversing the sort in one column by multiplying it by `-1`. Great work!

Comment: I tried this and I am getting "IndexError list index out of range. pointing to `the key[1] *= -1`

Comment: @octain Are you trying to apply this to a set of data where each line is shorter than three items? (e.g.  `30.0 10.5578` instead of `2 30.0 10.5578`)  If so, you'll get that error. In that case, you can fix it by changing `line.split()[1:]` to `line.split()`. If that's not the case, can you give me an example of data producing the error?

Answer (score 2):

```
def key(line):
    x,y = line.split()[1:]
    return (float(x),-float(y))

with open(fn) as f:    
    max((l for l in f if l.strip()),key=key)
```

Or with lambda,

```
with open(fn) as f:    
    max((l for l in f if l.strip()),key=lambda x: (float(x.split()[1]),-float(x.split()[2])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually as bad as it's made out to be, if your only goal is to read the file once and get that line.

```
max_col2 = -float('inf')
min_col3 = float('inf')
targetline = None
for line in f:
    idx, col2, col3 = line.split()
    if col2 > max_col2:
        targetline = line.strip()
        max_col2 = col2
    if col2 == max_col2 and col3 < min_col3:
        targetline = line.strip()
        min_col3 = col3
```

`targetline` will be your requested line.